# How to grant access permission for package in pipeline deployment?

Tags: salesforcedx, pipelines, sfdx-error

I'm trying to install package through pipelines for Scratch org push & test. I'm using this command in our yml file -

> *sfdx force:package:install --package 04t1Q000000kYu4 -w 10 -u ciorg*

Here is full line from yml file -

> *createScratchorg: &createScratchorg sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1 && sfdx force:package:install --package 04t6g000008SbHP -w 10 -u ciorg && sfdx force:package:install --package **04t1Q000000kYu4** --securitytype AllUsers -w 10 -u ciorg && sfdx force:source:push --targetusername ciorg && sfdx force:apex:test:run --targetusername ciorg --wait 10 --resultformat json --codecoverage && sfdx force:org:delete --targetusername ciorg --noprompt*

I've added component from this package on custom object's record page and I get this error -

> *Error  force-app/main/default/flexipages/PurchaseOrderRecordPage.flexipage-meta.xml
> We couldn't retrieve the design time component information for
> component NEILON:edLightningFileExplorer*

I suspect it might be related to access settings. During installation, it asks *Grant access (y/n)?*

I can't interact with pipeline installation so I assume it might be set to *n* by default. I was googling for parameters that might be useful in this situation but I didn't find any. Has anyone had similar problem or knows what I could do?

Comment: What is the component from the managed package that you are trying to use on the Lightning record page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cater "I suspect it might be related to access settings. During installation, it asks Grant access (y/n)?", try below:

If you're using shell script, you can try below -

```
echo y | sfdx force:package:install --package 04t1Q000000kYu4 -w 10 -u ciorg
```

Comment: *&createScratchorg sfdx force:org:create --definitionfile config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias ciorg --wait 10 --durationdays 1 && sfdx force:package:install --package 04t6g000008SbHP -w 10 -u ciorg && ECHO y | sfdx force:package:install --package 04t1Q000000kYu4 --securitytype AllUsers -w 10 -u ciorg && sfdx force:source:push --targetusername ciorg && sfdx force:apex:test:run --targetusername ciorg --wait 10 --resultformat json --codecoverage && sfdx force:org:delete --targetusername ciorg --noprompt*


Im not sure if I put ECHO in the right spot. I get bash: ECHO: command not found.

Comment: probably you're putting all in single command. lets break whichever command possible and then execute it.

Comment: same thing I have done and working (providing the Y input on waiting of program) on windows and linux machines. So I don't think its an issue in that approach.

Comment: It worked. I just needed to change it to lower case letters. Thanks!

Comment: Updated to lowercase, considering your scenario :-)